# Access Oracle Database remotely via DBeaver

Tags: oracle, remote, dbeaver

I have two machines, a windows 10 notebook with oracle database installed, and a Raspberry Pi 4 with DBeaver installed. On the Raspberry I have PostgreSQL which I can access locally via dbeaver, but since I'm studying and practicing Oracle DB, I need to access the database with the Raspberry. Is there any way to do it? Both machines are connected on the same wifi.

Comment: Did you install Oracle client software on your Raspberry? If not, this is where you should start.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, remote connections to an Oracle database is the standard way in real deployments.

Assuming there is nothing blocking communication between the two devices on your WiFi.

1. Start a listener on your notebook (`lsnrctl start`), the default one will start up using the your machine name as the host (this is ideal)
2. Make sure your instance is registering with the listener. Check with `lsnrctl status` for your instance. If it does not exist then check your `local_listener` parameter of your instance and add your machine name to it
3. Use the listener host in your connection string from your Raspberry Pi. Use an appropriate service name

Comment: Could you guide me step by step? I don't know anything about oracle but some basic sql language. Im studying Java and am at the JDBC topic, that's why I need to keep checking out the dbs I create. That said, I really dont know where to type lsnrctl, for example. Thanks for your time!